# How to remove Time Component from Ticks in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a column in SQL Server that represents `datetime` in `Ticks` form, hence the column type is `BigInt`.

I would like to remove the time component from the column leaving just the Ticks representing the date

Is this possible?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data -- or at least define what "ticks" means.

Comment: from question i assume that you want the date only from datetime field ? is this what you need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you can do this by division.  I don't know what a "tick" is.  But say it is a millisecond:

```
select (ticks / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) as start_of_day_ticks
```

If the ticks are microseconds then you would use `1000000`.

Answer (score 2):

By "Ticks" I assume you mean: "The number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001".
Then this should do it:

```
select Ticks - (Ticks % 864000000000)
```